# How to fix a cognitive distortion?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Are there any methods for "fixing" cognitive distortions?

For example, I have prejudice against certain type of people just because of one negative experiences in my life. Although a lot of research by my own show that I'm completely wrong to think this way about all people of the certain type I just can't fix my attitude towards them. It's like I'm programmed to think this way.

So what should person do in order to edit his/her beliefs if all necessary information about the topic is already obtained?

All advises I see are to research the topic or write pros and cons of the attitude but this isn't helpful because of established cognitive patterns which are in place for years.